# When editing ".svg" images, Inkscape is very very lagging. Who can tell me what should I do to make Inkscape run faster?

Tags: svg, inkscape

I used R to analyze the single-cell RNA sequencing data and save the t-sne and umap results to ".svg" images. When editing those ".svg" images, Inkscape is very very lagging. Who can tell me what should I do to make Inkscape run faster?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you probably have a very large number of nodes in your svg file. SVG files containing lots of node data will often be resource hungry and Inkscape can slow down.

If you can, export your data into separate files for editing and combine them again later. Alternatively, consider using raster images instead. Another option is to invest in a more powerful computer.

Comment: Also checkout https://inkscape.org/learn/tutorials/avoid-performance-issues/